# Why does the interval [1,1) not contain 1?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

On a quiz I was asked whether the interval [1,1) contained the number 1, and I answered that it was true, but apparently the answer is false.

But why doesn't it? I thought that "[1,1)" means "all numbers from 1 inclusive and 1 exclusive", so since 1 is included at the start it doesn't matter if it's excluded at the end since we already included it...

Comment: Usually $[a,b) := \{x\in\mathbb{R}:\ a \leq x < b\}$.

Comment: $[1,1)=\{x : 1 \leq x <1\}=\emptyset$

Comment: I think, @ChinnapparajR, you mean `\emptyset` or `\varnothing` ($\emptyset$, $\varnothing$), and not $\phi$.

Comment: Think of it this way: "$[a,b)$" means "The set of $c$ which are $\ge a$ **and** $<b$. It's that "and" which causes the problem.

Comment: @amWhy Sadly, some texts do use $\phi$ for the emptyset (I personally hate this, but it is a usage that occurs).

Comment: Oh! I get it now! Thanks!

Comment: Yea! In future I use that! (of course I edit that in my comment)

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* $[a,b) = \{ x \in \mathbb R : a \le x < b \}$. What real numbers $x$ satisfy $1 \le x < 1$ ?

Answer (score 2):

[a,a] = {a}

The only real number $x$ where $a\leq x\leq a$ is $a$.

[a,a) = $\phi$ (no items)

There is no real number $x$ where $a\leq  x<a$.

(a,a] = $\phi$  (no items)

There is no real number $x$ where $a<  x\leq a$.

(a,a) = $\phi$  (no items)

There is no real number $x$ where $a<  x< a$.

Answer (score 0):

No need to think more.
**Hint**What do you say about 0≤x<0. Is there exist any real number? Think about it.
You will get it.